# How to create .po files using xgettext on Windows?

Tags: php, gettext

I'm following this tutorial about building a multilingual web sites using PHP gettext http://onlamp.com/pub/a/php/2002/06/13/php.html

I understand the tutorial until this part:

> After you have the directories all
>   prepared, it's time to create the
>   actual "pot" file, as it is usually
>   referred to: the messages.po  file. To
>   do this, you will need to have PHP
>   files that use the gettext()  function
>   to "mark" strings to be translated and
>   use the xgettext  command.

```
$ xgettext -n *.php
```

Do I have to write that in the command line?
In which folder do I have to be when I execute that command?
Is that the Linux version of the command or for Windows?

(I enabled the gettext extension in my wamp ini file)
Do I have to download gettext utilites from the GNU web page in order to create .po files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use graphical tools like **Poedit** to create, edit and compile **.po** files :
http://www.poedit.net/

**Features** :

- Automatic compilation of .mo files (optional).
- You can use Poedit to scan source code for translatable strings.
- [...]

If you prefer the command line, **xgettext** (from the **gettext** tools) is the command to extract strings from sources. It's a **GNU** software available on Linux (already packaged for your distribution) and Windows (via Cygwin for example).

Comment: xgettext.exe is also included with Poedit (bin directory in its install path)

Comment: I believe EazyPo *might* also be used to parse source code files with an included binary of `xgettext` (even on Windows): http://www.eazypo.ca/.  But I have not confirmed this.