# Find / Detect / Format GetText strings used in files around

Tags: php, linux, gettext

Actually there are two questions:

1. is there a way to recursively pick up all GetText strings in current directory and all child dirs programmatically (using `exec` maybe or some)?
2. after i passed through the files within `xgettext` i got warning such as ...
   **internationalized messages should not contain the `\r**

So how to force xgettext to delete \n, \r, \t etc. automatically when string is found to avoid mentioned error so .PO file would be friendly formatted?

Thanks for coming links and advices :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closed. Only way i see - invoke xgettext from PHP as :

passthru('xgettext -n *.php', $result);

With params :

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.passthru.php
- [How to create .po files using xgettext on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258211/how-to-create-po-files-using-xgettext-on-windows)
- http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/gettext/xgettext-Invocation.html