# Best way to internationalize simple PHP website

Tags: php, internationalization, multilingual

I have to develop a pretty simple php website so I don't need framework. 
But it's must support multi language (EN/FR/CHINESE).
I have looked for php built in system and I found two ways :

- intl module from php5.3 (http://php.net/manual/fr/book.intl.php)
- gettext (http://php.net/manual/fr/book.gettext.php)

I have no experience in i18n without framework, so any advices about what's the **simplest way** to support multi language ?

At end I just need a function that search translation into file (one file by language).
EQ : 
`trans('hello');`

=> en.yaml (yaml or not, it's an example)

```
hello: "Hello world!"
```

=> fr.yaml

```
hello: "Bonjour tout le monde !"
```

And if possible I prefer Pure PHP implementations

Comment: You don't need your own function for that. `_('my text')` is an alias function for `gettext('my text')`. That alias is handy, when you need to call the function quite often, since it's less to write.

Comment: Don't use a framework but if you use gettext, definitely use the Zend_Translate library with the gettext adapter. Zend makes gettext very usable (which it is otherwise not).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Although `ext/gettext` and `ext/intl` are both related to i18 (internationalization), `gettext` deals with translation while `intl` deals with internationalizing things like number and date display, sorting orders and transliteration. So you'd actually need both for a complete i18-solution. Depending on your needs you may come up with an home-brew solution relying on the extensions mentioned above or your use components provided by some framework:

- **Translation**

  - [Symfony 2 Translation component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html): https://github.com/symfony/Translation
  - Zend Framework [`Zend_Translate`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.html)
- **Internationalization**

  - Zend Framework [`Zend_Locale`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.locale.html)

If you only need translation and the site is simple enough, perhaps your simple solution (reading a translation configuration file into an PHP array, using a simple function to retrieve a token) might be the easiest.

The most simple solution I can think of is:

```
$translation = array(
    'Hello world!' => array(
        'fr' => 'Bonjour tout le monde!',
        'de' => 'Hallo Welt!'
    )
);

if (!function_exists('gettext')) {
    function _($token, $lang = null) {
        global $translation;
        if (   empty($lang)
            || !array_key_exists($token, $translation)
            || !array_key_exists($lang, $translation[$token])
        ) {
            return $token;
        } else {
            return $translation[$token][$lang];
        }
    }
}

echo _('Hello World!');
```

Comment: Yeah I just ended a Symfony2 powered website with i18n so can be nice idea to chose its component. But this new project it's most a showcase website (At end less than 30 pages ...) with many static contents. Else really interesting answer thx.

Comment: I just implement your function just adding yaml support instead of pure php array for translation file !

Comment: @mowgli: You might have [`ext/gettext`](http://de3.php.net/_) installed already. `_` is an alias for the `gettext` function.

Comment: Ok. Inspired by your script, I have made something: http://pastebin.com/XL3qSiRF It's also simple and works pretty good (but could need improvement / more validation)

Answer (score 18):

I know this is an old question, but I feel that the answers are lacking a more hands-on approach from start to finish. This is what I did to get translation working using [PHP's `gettext` library](http://php.net/gettext) and [Poedit](https://poedit.net/) without using any additional PHP libraries on a Debian server:

### Preparation step 1: Install `gettext` and the locales on the server

I am not sure how this is done with other operating systems, but for Debian, you do:

```
sudo apt-get install gettext
sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

**Edit**: I assumed Ubuntu would be the same as Debian, but apparently it's slightly different. See [this page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/76013/how-do-i-add-locale-to-ubuntu-server) for instructions for installing locales on Ubuntu.

Make sure you select **all** of the locales that you want to use. You should then see something like:

```
Generating locales (this might take a while)...
  en_US.UTF-8... done
  es_MX.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.UTF-8... done
  zh_CN.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
```

### **Note:** Make sure you select the right *variants* and *character encodings* (most likely UTF-8) for each language. If you install `es_MX.UTF-8` and try to use `es_ES.UTF-8` or `es_MX.ISO-8859-1` it won't work.
Preparation step 2: Install Poedit on the translators' computers

Poedit is available from the software repository for most Linux operating systems. For Debian-based, just execute:

```
sudo apt-get install poedit
```

For Windows and Mac, go to: https://poedit.net/download

---

### Start coding:

Ok, now you're ready to get started coding. I wrote the following `gettext()` wrapper function to translate both singular and plurals:

```
function __($text, $plural=null, $number=null) {
    if (!isset($plural)) {
        return _($text);
    }
    return ngettext($text, $plural, $number);
}
```

Example usage:

```
// Singular
echo __('Hello world');

// Plural
$exp = 3;
printf(
    __(
        'Your account will expire in %d day',
        'Your account will expire in %d days',
        $exp
    ),
    $exp
);
```

This will work for all languages, not only languages where plural is anything where `n != 1` - this includes languages with multiple plural types.

You can also add translator notes like this:

```
/** NOTE: The name Coconut Hotel is a brand name and shouldn't be 
 translated.
*/
echo __('Welcome to Coconut Hotel');
```

You can change the text from `NOTE` to whatever you want, but you will have to alter it in the shell script below. **Important**: The translators note must be part of a comment on the line **immediately preceding** the `__()` function or it won't be picked up when we scan the PHP files for translatable strings.

```
// Warning! THIS WILL NOT WORK!
/* NOTE: This translator's note will not be picked up because it is
not immediately preceding the __() function. */
printf(
    __(
        'Your account will expire in %d day',
        'Your account will expire in %d days',
        $exp
    ),
    $exp
);
// Warning! THIS WILL NOT WORK!
```

After you are ready to send the strings off to the translators, save the following as a shell script (e.g. update.sh) in your application's root directory:

```
#!/bin/sh
find . -iname "*.php" | xargs xgettext --add-comments=NOTE --keyword=__:1,2 --keyword=__ --from-code=UTF-8 -o i18n.pot
find . -name '*.po' | xargs -I{} msgmerge -U {} i18n.pot
```

To execute it, just do:

```
cd /path/to/script && sh update.sh
```

This will recursively scan for all PHP files in that directory and create a `.pot` file (I called it `i18n.pot`, but feel free to name it whatever you like) and update any existing `.po` files it finds with the new strings.

We then need to create the directories that all the locale files will be stored, one for each locale. They need to be of the format `./locale/{locale}/LC_MESSAGES`. For example:

```
cd /path/to/your/project
mkdir -p ./locale/en_US.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES
mkdir -p ./locale/es_MX.UTF-8/LC_MESSAGES
# ...etc.
```

You need to decide on a text domain to use. This can be anything you want, but the script will look for a file called `{yourTextDomain}.mo` within the LC_MESSAGES folder for that language. Put the following in your PHP script:

```
define('TEXT_DOMAIN', 'yourdomain');
bindtextdomain(TEXT_DOMAIN, __DIR__.'/locale');
textdomain(TEXT_DOMAIN);
bind_textdomain_codeset(TEXT_DOMAIN, 'UTF-8');
```

Then to actually switch to another locale, do:

```
$lang = 'es_MX.UTF-8'; // Change this to the language you want to use
if (setlocale(LC_ALL, $lang) === false) {
    throw new Exception("Server error: The $lang locale is not installed. Please update the server's localisations.");
}
putenv('LC_ALL='.$lang);
```

Initially, you send the `.pot` file generated by the script above to the translators. They then open Poedit and click on `File > New from POT/PO file`. When they save it, they need to save it as `{yourTextDomain}.po`. The `{yourTextDomain}` needs to be exactly the same as the text domain you have in your PHP script. When they save it, it will automatically create both the `.po` file and the `.mo` file. Both of these need to be saved in that language's `LC_MESSAGES` directory when they are done translating.

Now when you update the strings in your PHP file, just re-execute the shell script and send the newly updated `.po` files to the translators. They then translate the strings and both the `.po` and `.mo` files need to be re-uploaded.

That's it. It may seem slightly difficult to get set up, but once you have it up and running, it's really easy.

Answer (score 3):

Gettext seems to be what you need.
There is a file by langage (except for the original one) and it's very easy to use :

```
echo _('Bonjour, ça va ?');
```

will print Hello , how are you ? in english.

There is [some tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258211/how-to-create-po-files-using-xgettext-on-windows) with gettext that could scan your php file and search for translatable string (in fact all string in _() or gettext()). Thanks to that you don't have to worry about the different langage file. You just code your website in the original langage and the langage file will automatically created later.

Nevertheless gettext is more a translation tools whereas intl is really an i18n one (number formating for example)

Answer (score 1):

Althought you don't need a framework you can use a framework. The internationalization features in Zend Framework is pretty good and you can just use that part of it instead of using all the parts (including MVC)

Comment: Can i just import i18n module from zend to my application ? (I already have my own lightness MVC framework)

Comment: How can you import just the translate part?

Comment: You can just copy that part, but you will also need the dependencies. Lots of the Zend Framework modules depends on roughly the following: Zend_Exception, Zend_Locale...

Comment: What I do is Include the Module I want, Run the app and it will throw Fatal error saying some module is missing. Then I copy that file too. But you can also copy the whole library too.