# How to have 2 languages in html so that I can open the page with a flag like lang=en?

Tags: php, html

I am making a html for showing a "Problem Statement" of a contest. The problem has translation in 2 language English and Bengali. I can make this using 2 htmls. But how can I have like this -
`desc.html?lang=en` or `desc.html?lang=bn` or some other kind so that I can tell the page to show a specific language?

I am a newbie in web development.

Comment: Do you currently have multiple pages for those languages?

Comment: @rpi Yes. But I want to have only one for 2

Comment: That would require some work with PHP. If you're using just URL to detect language, then with `$_GET` find which one (and have default, just in case) it is and include file that contains all constants. Use those constants in HTML file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to internationalize simple PHP website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953528/best-way-to-internationalize-simple-php-website)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Say, you have 2 files currently, `index-english.html` and `index-german.html`

You now create a file called `index-global.php`. <strike>Whether the first two pages are fully HTML or contain PHP, doesn't matter, but you should keep the current extension.</strike>Thanks to [fred-ii](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) for mentioning that you should change the extension to .php for the HTML-pages

In the `index-global.php` you'll place the following code

```
if (isset($_GET['lang']) AND $_GET['lang'] == "en") require("index-english.html");
elseif (isset($_GET['lang']) AND $_GET['lang'] == "de") require("index-german.html");
else {
    header("Location: /?lang=en"); //redirect if no language specified
    exit();
}
```

A better way would be to check the language automatically based on the `Accept-Language`-header, for example

```
$languages_supported_by_client = explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
foreach ($language_supported_by_client as $language) {
    if($language == "en") {
        require("index-english.html");
        exit();
    }
    elseif($language == "de") {
        require("index-german.html");
        exit();
    }
}
require("index-english.html");
exit();
```

In this case the asker wanted to include all HTML in one file

```
$languages_supported_by_client = explode(",",$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
foreach ($language_supported_by_client as $language) {
    if($language == "en") {
        ?>English HTML content here<?php
        exit();
    }
    elseif($language == "de") {
        ?>German HTML content here<?php
        exit();
    }
}
?>English HTML content here<?php
exit();
```

Comment: I didn't want like this. I want only one HTML where I can store both 2 Text. And I should be able to see only one text

Comment: The `.html` extension will only work if they instructed their system to treat `.html` files "as" PHP and if they want to run it on a local webserver. Your answer isn't entirely correct. You say *"Whether the first two pages are fully HTML or contain PHP, doesn't matter, but you should keep the current extension"* - Believe me, it does matter.

Comment: @RezwanArefin Read my comment above. I think it might fit.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas Still didn't get it :(

Comment: @rpi .. You still have 2 .html. I asked for only one html. Where I can store the problem statement and call it to show one

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii-, I've updated my answer

Comment: @rpi You're welcome.

Comment: @RezwanArefin, that's achievable by placing the current html files between the if's instead of the requires

Comment: @rpi Can I have only one .php to do this?

Comment: @RezwanArefin, that's exactly how I understood your last comment

Comment: I dont want my current 2 html. I want to have only one php / html to do that

Comment: Actually I am kind of absolute newbie in web development .. :(

Comment: Please read my updated answer, see last codeblock

Comment: Thanks. Get it :)